# Contact Form, how does it work?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm right about to launch my site, but first I need to finish my contact form, to make sure users can contact me. I'm not an expert in PHP or anything close, so please to understand my ignorance.

I have my server ready and running. I have an email. I have the site. I have two documents, one `contact.html` and the other `send.php`.

My `contact.html` has the following content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spotnight - About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="Favicon" href="f.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ham_container">
    <svg id="hamburger" title="Menu">
      <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#eeeeee" stroke-width="5"/>
      <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#eeeeee" stroke-width="5"/>
      <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#eeeeee" stroke-width="5"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/">Our Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/hybon.html">Hybon Sites</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/orion.html">Orion Interactives</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/studios.html">Spotnight Studios</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/shop.html">Spotnight Shop</a></li>
        <br>
      <li><a href="http://spotnight.io/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>Contact us! :)</h1>
    <h5>Spotnight</h5>
    <div>
      <form action="send.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name, eg: 'John'">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name, eg: 'Smith'">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email, eg: 'yourname@example.com'">
        <select name="subj" size="1">
          <option value="new_website">I need a website</option>
          <option value="new_game">I want a game</option>
          <option value="new_employee">I want to be part of the team</option>
          <option value="new_employee_game">I want to participate making games</option>
          <option value="new_employee_site">I want to participate building sites</option>
          <option value="new_artist">I'm an artist and need help</option>
          <option value="something_else">Something else!</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message Goes Here!"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send!">
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    &copy; <span id="year">2015</span> : <a href="http://hybon.spotnight.io/">Spotnight.io</a> : Proudly created by Hybon. 
  </footer>
</body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

My `send.php` document has the following content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subj = $_POST["subj"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $formcontent="From: " . $first_name . $last_name . ", " . $email . "\n Subject: " . $subj . "\n Message: " . $message;
    $recipient = "julian-avar@spotnight.io";
    $subject = "Contact Form - " . $subj . " - Spotnight.io";
    $mailheader = $email . " has tryed to reach you! \r\n";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You! Your message has been recived, we&apos;ll answer as soon as possible!" . $first_name . $last_name . " -" . "<a href="contact.html">Go Back!</a>";
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is all literal, meaning, the code is exactly as right there. I'm having trouble understanding it, and I still don't understand how it works.

So if you are a super duper awesome php expert, please help me understand and fix this code so I can deal with it later, and so other people understand how it works.

I have searched many places, but the simplest form of contact form doesn't seen to appear in the world archives. Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like a simple error, in your $formcontent line, you end it with $message"; remove the ", so it looks like this: $message;

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that, but even after I've updated it, it still doesn't seem to work, it just show me a blank page with `send.php`

Comment: @julian.a.avar — That sounds like your server doesn't support PHP.

Comment: Yes, it does, I'm using x10hosting, the free server, but even in the free servers they support PHP5

Comment: Go to View > Source in  your browser. Do you see the PHP source code?

Comment: In which page? `contact.html` or `send.php`?

Comment: you cant able to trace a PHP code from browser .. its an server side language ..browser not even know that what type of server script is used

Comment: Ok, so I should look at the source of `contact.html`?

Comment: no brother .. please look at this and first learn the concept behind it .. http://www.123contactform.com/simple-php-contact-form.html and this is pretty good http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

Comment: @julian.a.avar — `send.php` - there isn't any PHP source code in the other file.

Comment: @Sarath — Which is why it is a good test to see if the server is processing the server side code at all.

Comment: It is, it's solved, it is processing it, and it's great. Sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "Thank You! Your message has been recived, we&apos;ll answer as soon as possible!" . $first_name . $last_name . " -" . "<a href="contact.html">Go Back!</a>";
```

Here's the problem. The SO's code highliter highlights it badly because of it.

Use this instead:

```
echo /* part of code missing */ $first_name . $last_name . " -" . "<a href='contact.html'>Go Back!</a>";
//                                                    mind the ' signs here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You cannot include a quote in another quote without escaping the "'s or using a single-quote (I might have been mistaken in terminology) sign.

Comment: Wait what? I'm confused, what do I change?

Comment: `contact.html` must be surrounded with `'`'s not `"`'s

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Now it show the text, but I've been waiting for five minutes, the servers I'm using are not that slow, so it doesn't seem to solve it all the way...

Comment: @julian.a.avar, does your code work? If it doesn't, what exactly doesn't work? Does it send an e-mail?

Comment: It still doesn't, but right now I'm seeing if clearing all the HTML would help

Comment: It seems that there was a modem conection problem so I didn't need to erase all of the HTML. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your 'send.php' script mixes html with php so unless you are using output buffering you will encounter an error when it tries to send the email due to html content already being sent to the client/browser. I would suggest that the send.php script is pure php only. Also, the mailheader variable - this looks wrong to me - I think it should contain, at the very least, the From: email@domain.com field. From the PHP manual:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);





  <?php
    /* send.php */
    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subj = $_POST["subj"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];


    $formcontent="From: " . $first_name . $last_name . ", " . $email . "\n Subject: " . $subj . "\n Message: " . $message;
    $recipient = "julian-avar@spotnight.io";
    $subject = "Contact Form - " . $subj . " - Spotnight.io";
    $mailheader = "From: ".$email . "\r\n";

    $res = mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

    if( $res ) header( 'location:/index.php?mailsent=true' );
    else header( 'location:/index.php?mailsent=false' );
   ?>
```

Comment: So I only use `<?php ?>` and erase all the html, AND what else? Because I want the email to have all of that imformation, I don't want it to only have those three things: subject, message and headers

Comment: The example above was just that - an example. You can still include the various variables that you set in the 'send.php' script - but you do not need the html tags - once the mail has been sent you can redirect the user back to an html page using headers. ( header('location: /index.php' ) etc )

Comment: So I only erase all of the HTML and stick to the `<?php ?>`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems that I didn't need to erase the HTML after all.

Comment: *an error when it tries to send the email due to html content already being sent to the client/browser.* — nonsense. You get that error if you try to send HTTP response headers. Sending an email is completely independent  of constructing the HTTP response.